# Flutter: sliberAppBar stick icon to bottom

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am tired of experimenting with layout.. I just can't find the way how to align menu icon to the bottom of sliverAppBar. It should stick to the bottom permanently while sliverAppBar is being resized.

[image]

```
SliverAppBar(
  expandedHeight: 200.0,
  floating: false,
  pinned: true,
  elevation: 0.0,
  /*leading: Column( // <-- icon positioned in the upper section of appBar
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: <Widget>[
      Icon(Icons.menu, size: 40,)
    ],
  ),*/
  flexibleSpace: SafeArea(child:
    FlexibleSpaceBar(
      background: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Image.asset(
            'assets/images/store.png',
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            width: 120,
            height: 120,
          )
        ],
      ),
      title: Row( // <-- hides icon when appBar is spreaded out
        children: <Widget>[
          Icon(Icons.menu, size: 40, color: Colors.white,)
        ],
      ),
    )
  )
),
```

None of these approaches work as I expected.

I just want to align this icon permanently to the left bottom corner of the appBar. I don't want to hide icon when appBar reveals also I don't want to leave it in the upper section of appBar. How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Use **action** parameter inside SliverAppBar, 
After that you can design the way you want with *action* parameter
E.g

```
SliverAppBar(
          expandedHeight: 180.0,
          backgroundColor: mytheme.Colors.primaryColor,
          actions: <Widget>[

               ],
        ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Place the menu icon at the `title`. by default `SliverAppBar` title has a padding of `EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(start: 72, bottom: 16)` so change it to `EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(start: 16, bottom: 16)` then it will look something like below

[image]

```
  SliverAppBar(
              expandedHeight: 200.0,
              floating: false,
              pinned: true,
              elevation: 0.0,
              flexibleSpace: SafeArea(
                  child: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                background: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [FlutterLogo(size: 100.0,)],
                ),
               titlePadding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(start: 16, bottom: 16),
               title: Icon(
                      Icons.menu,
                      size: 40,
                      color: Colors.white,
                  )
          ))),
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Where should I put `EdgeInsetsDirectional` ?

Comment: @mr.boris at the `textPadding`. I updated the code. please check again

Comment: Thank you for advice! But it still behaves not as I expected. If I add more padding to the left edge (start: 100), everything is ok when appBar is revealed. When it collapsed icon moves to the center of the title widget. Also icon is resized as well. I just want to attach menu icon to the left bottom corner that's all. [Look at screenshot](https://ibb.co/Tch2qJB). There is no need of fancy transition in my case, it's annoying and poorly documented.